# Sending a structure over socket in c

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, send, recv

I am writing a program which uses socket programming in c.

In this program a client and server keep transmitting and receiving data.

When I send and receive integers over the socket using this kind of code

```
//in the program sending data
int data;
len= send(s,(char *)&(data),sizeof(data),0);

//in the program receiving data
int num;
len = recv(s,&num, sizeof(num) , 0);
```

The above code is working fine and I am able to transmit and receive numbers.

In one case I am trying to send a structure of the form

```
struct sample{
int num;
char chain[10*hops+10];
};

//in the program sending data
struct sample s1;
len= send(s,(char *)&(s1),sizeof(s1),0);

//in the program receiving data
struct sample s2;
len = recv(s,&s2, sizeof(s2) , 0);
```

In the example where I am trying to send and receive structure it is not working. How to send and receive the struct successfully ?

Note: 
1) Hops is a pre defined variable.The value of hops is same in both the programs.
2) By not working I meant : when I receive the struct and print the value in the the num. It is printing not the same value but zero!

Comment: `not working` .. please clarify. what is `hops`?

Comment: Can you show your full code..?

Comment: There are multiple problems that can arise from sending structures directly like that: First of all is the padding issue, if you compile sender and receiver using different compilers, they may add different padding in the structure. Print e.g. `sizeof(struct sample)` in both programs. Then there is the issue of byte order, do both systems you send between have the same [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)? And lastly, is `hops` the same in both the sender and receiver?

Comment: If none of the previous problems are issues for you, it *should* work, and you need to describe your problems in more details.

Comment: While reviewing your code, [Sending struct over socket in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817280/send-struct-over-socket-in-c) would seem to be at least informative.

Comment: You forgot to check the return value of `recv`!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - what a surprise:(

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to send the struct you must use serialization and deserialization, read about that, you can start with :

[Serialization issues while sending struct over socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565265/serialization-issues-while-sending-struct-over-socket)

Comment: i don't think so. `struct` itself represents a byte strings already, which naturally is serialized. that's not why OP failed to receive data.